# How To Disable Comments For One Wordpress Page

Tags: wordpress, comments, html

I know the technique by which I could disable comments permanently for a wordpress blog, however I wish to clarify how I could disable comments only for a certain page/post of a wordpress blog

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see this link to disable one page or post: 
[Disable Comments in wordpress](http://en.support.wordpress.com/enable-disable-comments/)

See my screeshots : 
[image]

[image]

Comment: thnx, but i also want to know how to disable the categories, recent posts and other widgets only for a certain page. So that there would be more room for the article on that page

Comment: Hi @Yoosuf,  if you want to display specific widget in specific page then you can use http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic-visual/ or this kind of plugin. Thanks

Comment: No I am not referring to any third party widgets, I am referring to the default widgets automatically added by wordpress. Is there a way to remove them from a particular page

Comment: i think there is no way without plugin or coding in wordpress themes file but i am not sure.

Comment: Ok thnx, I just have one more question. When I upload the files to the server and click on a link, it automatically redirects to my local machine, localhost. Is there a way by which I could change this to open the files from the FTP and not from my local machine

Comment: i follow this step with my own way: export database in sql format then search & replace my localhost url with live url. example: http://localhost/wp/ replace with http://syedahmed.me/. After that save sql file and import into live database.  thats all thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26596/discussion-between-syed-ahmed-and-yoosuf)

Answer (score 0):

There is already inbult functionality for disable comments for perticular post.You can disable by disucssion panel on bottom of perticular page.See here for all steps

http://blog.i13websolution.com/wordpress-how-to-disable-comments-on-particular-post/